# apoc.path.subgraphAll - How to Set Blacklist and Return Only Wanted Nodes & Relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

Further to [apoc.path.subgraphAll Doesn't Return a Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62968588/apoc-path-subgraphall-doesnt-return-a-graph/63009429#63009429) I'm trying to return a sequence of paths using:

```
MATCH (av:Architecture_View {`view identifier`:'SV-01'})-[:`HAS PART`]->(av_child:Architecture_View),(excludedNode:Node:TRAK)
WHERE excludedNode.name IN ['Software','Role','Physical','Organisation','Job']
//pattern is (Architecture_View)-[:SUPPLIES]->(Node)-[:`SUPPLIED TO`]->(Architecture_View)
CALL apoc.path.subgraphAll(av,{
beginSequenceAtStart: true,
sequence: "Architecture_View,SUPPLIES>,Node,`SUPPLIED TO`>,Architecture_View",
blackListNodes:[excludedNode]
})
YIELD nodes, relationships
RETURN nodes, relationships;
```

The problem with this is that:-

- the blacklist specified in blackListNodes:[excludedNode] doesn't work - these nodes are returned in the result set
- the returned graph includes paths that aren't in the specified sequence

[image: Result Graph - Showing Paths Not in Sequence]

Is my specification of the sequence and / or blacklist incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a typo in [the documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/graph-querying/expand-subgraph/#expand-subgraph-config).

Looking in the [actual code](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/blob/16581f3253f82e75506428dfd2a498346c6bfb1d/core/src/main/java/apoc/path/PathExplorer.java#L153), the "List" in "blackListNodes" should have a lower-case "L". That is, it should be "blacklistNodes".

You should create an [issue](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/issues) against the documentation so that this does not affect future users.

Comment: It might be true that the documentation contains an error wrt 'blackList' however changing to 'blacklist' produces the same result i.e. no filtering-out of blacklist items.